# Building opencv2.4.8 with Qt5.2

Tags: opencv, cmake, qt5

I am trying to build opencv2.4.8 from source with Qt support. I am using VS2013 on windows 7 professional with CMAKE 2.8.12. I keep receiving error:
error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'   C:\OpenCV\Myfiles\modules\highgui\Qt5Core.lib(Qt5Core.dll)  opencv_highgui

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just needed to build the Qt using "VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt". Before I built it with "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" which did not work.